# Add a new section to the PE and then puts a function inside of it

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have written this code to add a new section to my PE file and then put my function inside of it but it doesn't work. When I compile it and then open it in a pe viewer program (cff explorer), I didn't see this new section there.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

#pragma comment(linker, "/OPT:NOREF")
#pragma optimize( "", off )
#pragma section(".mk_ultra",read,write,execute)


__declspec(code_seg(".mk_ultra"))

void show_something()
{
    std::string source = "Blah blah blah.";
    
    WriteConsole(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), source.c_str(), source.length(), NULL, NULL);
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    show_something();

    return 0;
}
```

where is my mistake?

Comment: use `#pragma code_seg(".mk_ultra")`

Comment: It doesn't work.

Comment: for me this work

Comment: I used vs2022 and i can't get result from ti.

Comment: version of vs here unrelated